# Collision in different layer

Tags: unity, collision-detection, gameobject

I have a game object called gameObject1 on the screen. It holds an image called red. When I drag an image called  "animal" on  gameObject1 the collision happens correctly and destroys the "animal" in the same layer. Then I increment the score, but when I drag an image called  "animal" on  gameObject2 I want to decrement my score (with out collision). I know the collision on a different is not happening. [image]

```
 void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {

            if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Semi arid" )
        { 
            //obj1.rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
                scoreCalculate.currentScore+=10 ;

                Destroy(gameObject);
                //Debug.Log ("Scored1............"+scoreCalculate.currentScore);
                Instantiate(obj1, ObjectSpawnPosition1, Quaternion.identity);
                Instantiate(green, ObjectSpawnPosition1, Quaternion.identity);
                obj1.renderer.enabled = true;
                green.renderer.enabled = true;}
```

Answer (score 1):

To disable collision between specific layers you should go to in

Edit->Project Settings->Physics

and customize the collision matrix, which specifies for each layer combination if they can collide or not.

See [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html), hope it helps.

If it isn't happening yet, then reasons could be just because you use OnCollisionEnter2D instead of OnTriggerEnter2D() or because you move the transform instead of the Rigidbody2d.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of collision detection, you can use raycasting. When an object starts to be dragged, perform raytest inside the Update by filtering unwanted objects.

```
RaycastHit info;
int layerMask = (1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("GO1Layer") | 1<<LayerMask.NameToLayer("GO2Layer"));
if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out info, 100f, layerMask))
{
    if (info.collider.name == "GO1")
        //statements
    else if (info.collider.name == "GO2")
        //statements
    else
        //statements
 }
```

Put this into a mouse listener script. Check whether an object is getting dragged and set the layermask to ignore the dragged object.

Comment: how ? when i drag this game object "animal" upon the "gameobject 2"  how it decrement the score.

Comment: I meant always. Try sending raycasts from the mouse origin to the corresponding scene area while some object is dragged. In this way, you can filter whatever you want without colliding objects.

Comment: can you provide me a sample code wht u meant?